# react native if else statement won't run function automatically

Tags: reactjs, react-native, if-statement

trying to run a function on a if else statement in react native, however if I just call it straight up like this.removeAlert() I get an infinite loop crash because of calling setState. I read that you should call it within a function, which works fine in onPress functions, but for me its not working outside of that.

```js
  class Settingscontainer extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.removeAlert = this.removeAlert.bind(this);
  }
  removeAlert = () => {
    console.log("please work");
    // this.setState({ successAlert: false });
  };

  render() {
    this.props.isFocused
      ? console.log("Focused") // console.log working
      : () => {                // not working
          this.removeAlert();
        };
    return(<View>code...</View>
    )  
    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is equivalent to this:

```
function callRemoveAlert() {
  this.removeAlert();
}
this.props.isFocused
    ? console.log("Focused")
    : callRemoveAlert
```

You define a function to call `this.removeAlert()`, but never invoke that function. To make your code work, you need to do:

```
this.props.isFocused
    ? console.log("Focused")
    : this.removeAlert()
```

But since in `removeAlert`, you intend to modify state, so **I don't think you should do it this way**. By default, React component, with every change in props and state, will invoke `render`. With your implementation, `render` will trigger `setState`, and state change will trigger `render`, causing an infinite loop of state update and render. A better way to do this is to use `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.isFocused !== prevProps.isFocused) {
      (this.props.isFocused) ?
      ? console.log("Focused")
      : this.removeAlert();
    }
}

render() {
    return(<View>code...</View>
    )  
    }}
```

Comment: haha thanks for the new info explaining the loop, i ended up with more or less the same answer before i saw yours.